# Xcode 10 simulator freeze up on iPads and iPhone XS Max

Tags: simulator, xcode10

Upgraded to Xcode yesterday.
Now iPads and iPhone XS Max simulator aren't working.
Simulator blank screen came up, but no Apple logo.
Other simulators are fine, such as iPhone 8, iPhone XR.
My machine is MacBook Pro, 15", mid 2010, 8G RAM, 200G free space in hard drive (SSD).
Xcode 9 was very smooth.

Comment: All the plus models and iPads don't work. Seems like it affects most of the 2011 or earlier MacBooks.

Comment: It freezes on iPhone 8 (iOS 12) as well. Often, after sitting on a breakpoint.